# How to get a starting letter of each word in capital letter in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a value like this `view benefit:detail:full bony impacted` . I want to get starting letter of each word in `Capital letters` in `Hive` .

Output should be like as follows .

`View Benefit:Detail:Full Bony Impacted`

Please provide me a query for this in `Hive`.

Answer (score 0):

If the colon characters `:` are fixed to two occurrences, you could try something like this:

```
select concat(initcap(split('view benefit:detail:full bony impacted',':')[0]),':', initcap(split('view benefit:detail:full bony impacted',':')[1]),':',initcap(split('view benefit:detail:full bony impacted',':')[2])) AS comment;
```

output

```
+-----------------------------------------+--+
|                 comment                 |
+-----------------------------------------+--+
| View Benefit:Detail:Full Bony Impacted  |
+-----------------------------------------+--+
```